Lookbehing regex and escaping pattern
I'd like to do a lookbehind regex substitution with:
pattern = '<test foo="bar">'

re.sub(r'(?<=the_actual_pattern)', ...

When a pattern contains characters to be escaped, how to do it correctly?
Should we use:
re.sub(rf'(?<={pattern})', ...    # combination of r'...' and f"..." string

or
re.sub(rf'(?<=<test foo="bar">)', ...  # won't work because < and " are not escaped

and:
more generally, what is the standard re.sub regex way to do a lookbehind regex substitution with a pattern containing to-be-escaped strings?

As per the linked duplicate, use re.escape(pattern) like this: re.sub(f'(?<={re.escape(pattern)})', ...

rf'(?<=<test foo="bar">)' will work fine anyway since neither < nor " are special. But in a general case, yes, re.escape is what you ask for.

@WiktorStribiżew Oh I did not know that neither < nor " are special. Then, how does the regex engine distinguish the special < from ?<=  from the < from <test foo="bar">?

It parses the pattern and uses in-built programming logic behind the scenes.
